# Call back at iTunes login prompt appearance

Tags: ios, parse-platform, in-app-purchase, uiactivityindicatorview

When handling inApp purchase (using Parse.com) in an iOS app, the user clicks BUY and waits for the iTunes login (or enter password) prompt to come up.
During the waiting time, I display and activityView to ask the user to wait.
Then when the prompt shows up, I need to clean this activityView.
What is the call back function I need to put the code into?
Is there something like loginPromptDidAppear? From which I could clean off the activityView.

Comment: I am not 100% certain as I am not at my computer but I suspect that `applicationWillResignActive` will be called in your AppDelegate

Comment: I am not sure I see the connection with the event I am trying to track. Namely the appearance of the  iTunes login prompt.

Comment: As the prompt is issued by iOS, not your app, I suspect that you will get a call to `applicationWillResignActive` just as you would if there is a phone call - as I said, I can't confirm this right now which is why I haven't put it as an answer, but it would be interesting to see what happens if you put an NSLog into that app delegate method and test your in-app purchase.  Otherwise there is no other event or delegate method that informs your app of the in-app purchase progress

Comment: Yes! It works as you explain. Thanks a lot. Please put this as an answer and I will mark it as "accepted answer". I would suggest, much better including the explanation in your second comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the prompt is issued by iOS, not your app,  you will get a call to  the `applicationWillResignActive` method in your app delegate,  just as you would if a phone call is received.

You should be able to track your app operation (i.e. purchase initiated) and react accordingly when your app resigns active state.