# InApp Purchase - How to detect "Buy" button for the 'Confirm Your In App Purchase' is displayed

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

when the 'Confirm Your In App Purchase' Alert is displayed , there are two buttons "Buy" and "Cancel" . I need to know when the "Buy" button clicked . So that i can start some activity Indicator for the user .

Thanks In Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call back at iTunes login prompt appearance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871920/call-back-at-itunes-login-prompt-appearance)

Comment: i am expecting any delegate to identify the buy events for app . So that i can start activity indicator . And i can remove the indicator in applicationWillResignActive in appdelegate

Comment: No, there are no such delegate events.  You can start an activity indicator as soon as you submit the purchase request.  Once your app returns to the active state you know that the purchase dialogs have completed

Comment: as soon as i submit the purchase request i start an activity indicator but need to remove it while 'Confirm Your In App Purchase' Alert is appeared . Then on click of buy till success i need an activity indicator . So i am expecting anything to notify for the "Buy" clicked event , so that i can start  activity indicator .

Comment: Once you submit a purchase request your app leaves the active state and doesn't receive any further notifications until it returns to the active state.  All of the purchase/buy dialogs are provided by iOS